# Associated elements of a Euclidean domain have the same values of associated function

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $D$ be a Euclidean domain and $d$ be the associated function. Show that if $a$ and $b$ are associates in $D$ then $d(a)=d(b)$.

I'm not  even getting how to begin this. Any hints are welcome. Does  $\left< a \right>=\left< b \right>$ imply $d(a)=d(b)$?

I have proved that if $a $ and  $b$ are associates then $\left< a \right>=\left< b \right>$, but I'm not getting how to proceed towards $d(a)=d(b)$.

Comment: Does your Euclidean function require the property $d(x) \leqslant d(xy)$ for all nonzero $x, y \in D$?

Comment: @Alex Wertheim :yeah!

Answer (score 4):

One has $b=ua$ for some invertible element $u$ in $D$. Hence $$d(b)=d(ua) \geqq d(a).$$ On the other hand, $$d(a) =d(u^{-1}b) \geqq d(b).$$

Comment: :thanks! also it means  < a >=< b > implies d(a)=d(b)?

Comment: (I'm assuming that by $\langle a \rangle$ you mean the ideal generated by $a$.) Note that $\langle a \rangle = \langle b \rangle$ in a domain $A$ is equivalent to $a = ub$, for some unit $u$ in $A$.